# Getting exception "Unknown Error" after bundling the application(exe)

Tags: html, exe, jxbrowser

We are using the evaluation version of JXBrowser for some charting application. We wanted to showcase a demo to our client just to check the overall performance of charts with JXBrowser. But we encountered some unexpected issue while we were trying to build an "EXE".

The issue:
    We created a build and the passed the URL from the `classpath(webView.getBrowser().loadURL(getClass().getResource("/chartiq/stx-advanced.html").toExternalForm()););` the build successfully generated and if we run the build we are getting exception "Unknown Error" but its working fine in the IDE(Eclipse).
    Afterwards, we tried to host the html pages at some server and we were able to get the html rendered in the application.

Question:
    1. Is the aforementioned issue related to evaluation version?
    2. If above question is not the case, is there any fix for that? As we have crawled the web and find nothing related to this.

For the reference I attached the screen shot showing the full exception stacktrace.
[image: 1]

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this issue is that JxBrowser doesn't support loading resources from JAR files. Chromium engine used in JxBrowser cannot load the `/chartiq/stx-advanced.html` file located inside JAR archive. You need to extract the file and load the extracted file.

FYI: we have already started working on the functionality that allows loading HTML files and other resources from JAR archives. An updated build with this functionality will be available in December.